# rails server just prints command usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

```
$ rails server
```

> Usage:
>         rails new APP_PATH [options]
>
> ```
> Options:
>   -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
>                                  # Default: /home/bikram/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
>
>   -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
>   -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
>       [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
>       [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
>   -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
>   -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
>   -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
>   -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options:
> ```
>
> mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
>                                        # Default: sqlite3
>         -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
>                                        # Default: jquery
>         -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
>             [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
>             [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
>         -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
>             [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9
>
> ```
> Runtime options:
>   -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
>   -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
>   -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
>   -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
>
> Rails options:
>   -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
>   -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
>
> Description:
>     The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
>     directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
>
>     You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
>     'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.
>
>     Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
>     defaults values shown above in this help message.
>
> Example:
>     rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
>
>
>
>     This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
>     See the README in the newly created application to get going.
> ```

It generated like this but not rails local server. Other versions are:

- Rails 3.2.14
- ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
- gem 2.1.9
- rvm 1.23.9 (stable)

my gem file is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the default message generated when you try to launch the Rails server in a folder without a Rails application.

You need to run `rails new <appname>` where appname is the folder you're in prior to launching the server.

If it is a Rails application, then you're likely missing some key files that the server command uses to determine if it is a Rails application.

Comment: i've perfectly did all the steps... still not working

the command is working with another application which i have had created earlier...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are running the command `rails server` while not in (the root directory) of a Rails application.

Change into your Rails project directory and try again.

Comment: i am exactly in the  root directory

Comment: even " rails generate rspec:install " this command is also giving me the same result